# html5 canvas circle issue

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a circle using html5 canvas. However, With my following code, it it does not make a circle it only makes egg shape.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/doforumda/5Kn5M/)

html

```
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

css

```
#canvas {
        display: block;
        width: 370px;
        height: 622px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        background-color: #ccc;
    }
```

js

```
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');


    context.beginPath();
    context.fillStyle = '#bb0000';
    context.arc(100, 100, 20, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    context.closePath();
    context.fill();
```

How to make a proper circle using html5 canvas?

Comment: change your height and width of [`#canvas`](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-circles/)

Answer (score 1):

Your JavaScript is completly correct, the shape of your circle is caused by your CSS.
The canvas is behaving like an image, and because the canvas itself has no size specified it uses the default size to display the context, which is then resized by your CSS.

Just change the size of the `#canvas` element:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="370" height="622"></canvas>
```

<kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5Kn5M/2/)**</kbd>